# What are the use cases for numeric values of log levels?

Tags: java, python, logging, log4j

In popular logging frameworks like Java's `log4j` or Python's `logging`, log levels have associated numerical values, please see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels).

Those numerical values are used to determine the severity of a given log level.

But are there any other actual use cases for this numerical value?

Comment: You should try reading the resources you link: *These are primarily of interest if you want to define your own levels, and need them to have specific values relative to the predefined levels.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you choose to log a given level, you also want to log higher gravity levels.

Associating each log level to an integer makes it much easier to determine if a specific level have to be logged or not because it actually is a simple comparison of this form:

```
if current_log_level >= wanted_log_level then log_it() else drop_it()
```

Let's say you want to log warnings, so you define your log level to `WARNING` which has a value of 30. Then...

- CRITICAL logs are logged because 50 >= 30 is True
- ERROR logs are logged because 40 >= 30 is True
- WARNING logs are logged because 30 >= 30 is True
- INFORMATION logs are NOT logged because 20 >= 30 is False
- DEBUG logs are NOT logged because 10 >= 30 is False

---

Just think about the needed code to resolve this simple problem if log levels were strings...